# GA snippet for same family domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have to a GA account and have to add GA snippet for each site. There are 5 websites e.g. domain names are

```
mysite.uk
mysite.fi
mysite.no
mysite.se
mysite.fr
```

Agency suggested since all domains belong to the same mysite.* family they may use the same GA snippet, with different country code.

Is it possible to use one GA snippet in above scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes. It is possible to do that.

Is it the best course of action? Possibly. It depends on exactly how you want to use the data. What I'd recommend does depend on if you use UA or GA4.

In GA4, you could use individual data feeds for each. This would allow you to combine all of the traffic and yet keep them separate.

In UA, you could have separate views, one master view combining all of the sites and then individual views for each site.